# OneStepCheckout - display subtotals of tax class

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, onestepcheckout

I am using Magento 2.1.1 and Module One Step Checkout from Magestore. If anyone is using that it would great, but I bet in default Magento it can ba achieved in similar way.I was digging around for a few days but so far I haven't succeeded.

I want to display subtotals for every tax classes for products in cart. For example if I have one product for 100$ and its tax class is 8-taxabale goods and another for 100$ with 23-taxable goods I want to render info nearby total for whole order, that

`var 8%: 8$
 vat 23%: 23$`

The thing is that I don't know how to do it in knockout templates. I have noticed that every `.html`has its own `.js` file with same name so I guess every js provides functionality for connected html. Should I add some methods in this js, overriding it in my custom theme.

For example:

`totals.html`

`<!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->`

and `totals.js`
`define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total'
    ],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';

```
    return Component.extend({
        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        isDisplayed: function () {
            return this.isFullMode();
        }
    });
}
```

);
`

Where I should start debugging? How can I look up what data exactly I have in html template? These `ko` `comments` in html templates seems hard to debug. I was trying to add ANY content (like `<h1>Test</h1>`) in `totals.html` but nothing is displayed, but when I added something in main html template of OSC - `onestepcheckout.html` everything is displayed. Of course I have tried to clear magento and browser cache, as well as clear `pub/static/*`.